# How to config CAS 5.3 with LDAP

Tags: cas, openldap

I'm using CAS 5.3.2. I found this [guide](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/LDAP-Authentication.html) for my installation. Added the "compile" line and build succeed. But I don't know how to make a full configuration to link my LDAP with this CAS. The doc looks simple.
Anyone can show me a simple example?
Thanks!